Would all disagreements vanish if everyone had access to the same information and followed the same reasoning process?
A closely related question is posed here: How can experts disagree despite having access to the same facts?. That question focuses on different experts having access to the same set of facts—i.e., the same data or information. However, it does not address the aspect of following the same reasoning method. Is there a reasoning method that functions as a deterministic algorithm, where the input is a set of facts or data? If such a method exists, wouldn't all disagreements disappear if everyone had access to the same facts and used this exact reasoning process? Since the reasoning would be deterministic and the input fixed, the output should likewise be fixed, leading to universal agreement.
This concept could potentially be applied to resolve debates such as:

Theism vs. Atheism: We could compile all the facts that theists and atheists are aware of, take the union of these fact sets, and then apply a standard deterministic reasoning method to see whether the conclusion "God exists" emerges.
Free Will vs. Determinism: By gathering all relevant facts from both perspectives and applying the same deterministic reasoning method, we could determine whether the conclusion supports free will or determinism.
Moral Objectivism vs. Moral Relativism: We could combine the facts supporting both views and apply a deterministic reasoning method to see whether morality is objective or culturally relative.
Etcetera.


I've often thought and frequently said that the truth should smack one in the face so hard that they see stars. (That's what happened to Astronomers.) In other words: that it is simply impossible to imagine anything different. Until that happens, gather more data. I wonder in the Question though about the idea of gathering the 'union' of both sets of views. Shouldn't that be the intersection? If there is no useful intersection, then one of the sides is at sea. If there are multiple sides, my guess is they are all at sea. But, you know, 400 high-level programming languages and counting, I

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Perhaps this is relevant to the recent discussions involving permissiveness / impermissiveness?

@ScottRowe I definitely think so.

I think it's trivially the case that following the same deterministic process given the same inputs leads to the same outputs.
If we agreed on or shared a deterministic reasoning process, a lot of disagreements should be resolved, but we don't have that (or at least there are additional hidden inputs).
Reasoning is heavily affected by one's cognitive biases, such as stereotyping, a tendency to stick to what one already believes and various emotional appeals of claims. You have a lifetime worth of experiences, as well as natural tendencies, that affects your reasoning.
Although working with different sets of information is also a big source of disagreement. As an example, there is near-universal agreement in the scientific community (especially in relevant fields) about evolution, the age of the Earth, climate change, gender identity, etc. But plenty of laypeople, who aren't neck-deep in the data, don't agree on those things. People try to explain that with all manner of conspiracy theories, but the much simpler explanation is that laypeople just aren't as intimately familiar with the data. Whether or not one is a scientist probably also affects one's cognitive biases, with regard to evaluating scientific research: if you are intimately familiar with how science is done, it's less likely that one would dismiss conclusions others reached through valid science because of one's cognitive biases, even if you aren't in that field yourself and you aren't as familiar with the data.
* In this age of computers and supercomputers, maybe it's viable to create a deterministic algorithm to evaluate facts and construct a worldview, where people could broadly agree on what valid inferences are and on the input facts. But this would be quite an ambitious project, and I expect most people will just dismiss output they disagree with in any case, by assuming there's a bug, some inferences are incorrect or some input data is incorrect.

Or to put it another way: there are hidden variables here, and the premise of having the same information is essentially unattainable unless people have had identical life experiences all the way down to the biochemical level, and possibly to the quantum level. At which point, you have basically said that people don't disagree with themselves.  But even that is not always true, especially if you ask them the same question at different times; people can and do change their minds.

If you allow that our values or utilities differ -- minimally that I value me over you -- expect disagreements over decisions that affect us differently, even if we have the same model and data. (See @Lowri's answer.) Though in a perfect game among clones-in-the-matrix, even if we want opposite things, we would each know perfectly well what the other wants and why.

Consensus among the best informed people around does suggest that to be the more likely conclusion based on available evidence. Remember that we're dealing in models, not absolutes. Models can and do fail, but they remain useful because they work most of the time. Scientific consensus works most of the time; the exceptions tend to be edge cases, which may force us to reevaluate the basics but do not refute the fact that the model was useful up until that point.  And science explicitly accepts that it can make mistakes, and eventually corrects them when the gator requires it.

Newtonian physics isn't perfect. But it's still close enough to be a useful model. The same is undoubtedly true of all of our models of the universe, but the consensus model is the consensus for a reason: so far, it has worked, and when it hasn't, we have changed the consensus. Seeking absolutes is fine in philosophy, but not in philosophy of science.

You first ask:

Would all disagreements vanish if everyone had access to the same information and followed the same reasoning process?

Access to the same information does not sufficiently constrain the inputs even to a deterministic reasoning algorithm. Other inputs that are left under-determined in your hypothetical include:

one's own values and preferences and goals
one's attention to any given fact (the salience of that fact to a given individual)
the moral theory that the person is operating under
etc.

However, later in your question you refer to the "input" being fixed, not just the facts. If that goes so far as to eliminate any variation in any input, and that fixed input is entered into a deterministic algorithm, then yes, it would produce a consistent result.
Note that people developed bodies
from different DNA, developed in a different wombs, have had different sensory experiences throughout life, etc. All would be differences in input that I cannot imagine how you would eliminate in practice.

Not particularly, the question presuposes that humans are purly logical in their reasoning, most humans are not. Most humans (possibly just many humans, I'm not sure on this point) are capible of logic but dont use it unless they need to, humans are largly emotional creatures with a host of biases that will make an attempt at unified logic fail. For instance, being more forgiving to the problems with positions they like then positions they dont like, or having a more positive view of an idea that they helped make, then an equal idea that they didn't have a hand in making.
In practice, this would only compound with issues around ambiguity in what different words mean, or differences in what the goal is (if you were just asked to change your mind on something you hold as fundamental, would you?).

Already in the 17th century, Leibniz wrote:

The only way to rectify our reasonings is to make them as tangible as those of the Mathematicians, so that we can find our error at a glance, and when there are disputes among persons, we can simply say: Let us calculate, without further ado, to see who is right.

So the dream of resolving disputes through calculation is almost as old as modern mathematics itself.  Unfortunately, the implementation phase has been delayed.

Your basic premise is virtually impossible. You say "the same set of facts", but the facts that are used when making decisions or judgements include all the experiences of the person's life, not just the results of any particular experiment or set of experiments. And not just things they've experienced personally, but recountings from other people.
On top of that, memory is fallible and malleable, so some of these "facts" may change over time.
Consider, for example, the kinds of viewpoints that people have about the police after hearing about something like George Floyd being killed by a police officer. White people who have never experienced racism will see this very differently from black people who encounter it on a daily basis. White children never get "the talk" from their parents about how to act when stopped by a cop. This establishes very different biases when making political decisions later in life, even though they may read the exact same news accounts.
A few weeks ago millions of people watched the same debate between Harris and Trump. We heard all the same words, but we came away from it with different feelings, due to our preexisting political leanings.
If you want to make an analogy, it's like a chaotic physical system. Theoretically, if you knew the initial states of all particles to sufficient precision, you could predict the entire future of the system. But "sufficient precision" is not possible, and small differences can produce vastly different futures (the so-called "butterfly effect"). And in the case of people, the starting conditions can be very different.

Ok, good point about the 'chaotic' differences in people's backgrounds. But when making large-scale or long-term decisions, we are supposed to get over our personal biases, otherwise why are we even discussing anything? Part of reasoning is really actually using reason, not just post-hoc justification.

You can't "get over it". You can't even understand language or the nature of the experimental results without resorting to your history. Everything you perceive is filtered through a brain that has been shaped by your past experience.

Why does a quarrelsome couple stay together? -- Perhaps they like bickering, perhaps each likes a bit of opposition, a bit of verbal display. Without any disagreement life would be so boring!
A disagreement may be disagreeable to the parties involved. They may look for ways to resolve it. But to a third party the disagreement may be an opportunity. In the simplest case, an opportunity to "take sides" ("community building"). In other cases, an opportunity to get rich -- which may be an incentive to keep the original disagreement going. Every war has its arms dealers and many would be more than happy to supply both sides with the very latest arms ("winning methods for your philosophical disputes").
Assume all (relevant) disagreement would indeed vanish. This could be incredibly dangerous for the survival of our species. If the agreement itself distorts the "facts" in any way, then being in agreement is not a value but something to be avoided. Totalitarian or autocratic, non-pluralistic societies that enforce agreement and limit the available, "acceptable" beliefs are not pleasant to live in.
Suppose all philosophical disagreements would have been resolved, then that would be the end of Philosophy StackExchange.

A little bit more formally. Given some data, i.e. given a finite set of observations that two observers agree on and given the exact same methods of general reasoning that they both use, it is always possible to develop different models about that data set. (If you assume that they have the exact same methods of discovery, you are basically assuming they are clones of each other. In that case the whole problem is trivial and uninteresting. I'm not making assumptions about their creativity or pattern recognition skills, merely that they both are normal, smart human beings with similar background knowledge and abilities.)
Any kind of reasoned, justifiable prediction can only be based on some model (understanding, explanation of the data). In the simplest case you may have a finite sequence of numbers. The question is to find out what "the" rule is that generates this sequence (in order to make a falsifiable model to predict the next number). The simple answer is that "the" rule does not exist. There are always infinitely many rules that "conform to" or "generate" the initial finite set. (Aumann's theorem therefore seems irrelevant to me in all interesting practical cases.)
For an interesting example and discussion of this issue, see the first chapter of Fluid Concepts about the "Seek Whence" project. Hofstadter describes in that chapter how he, as a teen, searched for (and ultimately found) a rule, a pattern to describe the given interleaved sequence of triangle numbers and squares

1 3 6 10 15 ... (triangle numbers)
1 4 9 16 25 ... (squares)
1 1 3 4 6 9 10 15 16 21 25 ... (interleaved, in ordinal order)

This interleaved sequence has some amazing, beautiful "properties" that are only discovered by trying out several hypotheses. (In this case, since we start from a given infinite sequence, it might make some sense to say that all rules that generate this sequence are "essentially identical", but saying that also "essentially" trivializes mathematics...)
Our general pre-scientific assumption is that there is some order in the world, there are patterns to be discovered in the data. So, we hope that some simplified model of the data will make it possible to deal with the world (retroactively explain all observations and proactively predict new ones). But there are always different models possible. (It's never a settled issue how the priors should or may be set in a Bayesian approach.) Even if some model seems "the" explanation, it always remains possible that someone made an error (in the data) or that more data will not "fit" nicely enough or that some "nuisance parameter", some edge condition, that we initially ignored as irrelevant turns out to be relevant.
Looking at the history of science should teach some humility. The main purpose of philosophy, according to me, is to try to inculcate open-mindedness, to teach yourself to doubt yourself, not to try gain absolute certainty.

I suppose the assumption is that people would come to the correct agreement if they are using reason.

GIGO. If you start with different initial conditions, don't be surprised when you get different final results, even if the processors are identical.

You ask:

Would all disagreements vanish if everyone had access to the same information and followed the same reasoning process?

No. Reasoning processes and information are only as relevant as what one wants to do with them. That is to say, the individual constitution and preference of the agent plays a roll in how reason and information are used. Two people, who have very different preferences will essentially use an argument in fundamentally different ways. In philosophy, axiology is the study of values, and two people have different values that sit behind reason and facts will ultimately think and behave in distinct ways.


You could look at these optical illusions (same data) in the same way (same reasoning process) and would still come out seeing different things. Also if your experts work in the same field they likely were trained on the same methods and processes, yet often enough the problem is that the data could be interpreted in multiply ways, so depending on which path they follow some of the data points will be fitting, other's will be "ok" and other's might be outliers. So it's not so much that they operate on different data, they value the existing data differently.
They might be able to understand what the other person is seeing and might not object to them seeing that or the utility of researching that as an alternate hypothesis, but they nonetheless might disagree with them if there's only 1 possible approach to follow and they have made their minds about choosing the other and evolved it so far that the 2 approaches are mutually exclusive.

So then you look at the results of both approaches. Everything that happens is data. If there is no useful difference in results, why worry about the issue at all?

But doesn't the fact that people prioritize different things mean that people are following different reasoning processes? So I don't see how this invalidates agreement when people do follow the same reasoning method. If two people value different things cognitively, then they are NOT reasoning in the same way.

@user80226 If you don't like explicitly priorities, well just picture your reasoning process be an algorithm that incorporates randomness. Like idk taking your math skills to gambling or stuff like that, you can have multiple agents apply the very same reactions to different turns of the table. And if you object that's not the same data, well picture them drawing balls from a bag. Same bag for all, same data, different outcome depending on what you draw. In some cases you might just get different results depending on where you start and that's not just hypothetical take AI algorithms.

Let's say we have two people with very strong priors.

Alice has a prior: there is no God, but it is possible that I might suffer from a mental illness one day. One day she hears a Voice: "Alice, this is God speaking", so she checks herself into a psychiatric hospital.
Bob is a Christian fundamentalist whose priors include God exists, and there is a Devil who can make people see and hear things that aren't really there. No amount of evidence can shake Bob's faith.

It seems to me that Alice and Bob will never agree regardless of evidence. OTOH, if their priors were weaker, "God might exist", with different sufficient statistics for the probability distribution, then they could get their beliefs to become arbitrarily close given "enough" shared evidence.
Afterthought: the evidence must be shared. Because I live in the Southern hemisphere, I have a prior belief that the Sun is to the North at noon; if I were to discuss this with a Norwegian, say, using email, we would never agree because his observations and mine reinforce our priors.

I don't understand your anology if you believe that the earth is a sphere. The north's experience is different than the South's experience, but it is explained that they are polar opposites?  Please clarify your argument.

@8Mad0Manc8 "if you believe that the earth is a sphere." I never argue with flat earthers. It's a waste of time. What is an "anology"?

Anology is not proof but it's a useful tool to support an argument. What's yours?

If it helps I think we're on the same page however a bit of clarity may help my confusion or worsen it :-)

@8Mad0Manc8 Perhaps you mean analogy?
I know a couple of people who are very good at navigating without a GPS, with just a quick glance at a map, just by reading cues from their surroundings. Except that one of them keeps getting lost whenever he visits the Northern hemisphere. He realized that he is subconsciously using the position of the Sun as a cue, i.e. he has "the Sun is North of me" as a prior, so he is orienting the map wrong.

@ScottRowe Priors? You only want one prior in a priory; two or more would only cause trouble.

I don’t just try to get to logical conclusions, I try to get a conclusion that benefits me. If I sell you my car, I want a conclusion that my car is worth $12,000 and you want a conclusion that it’s worth $10,000. So no, we won’t get to the same conclusion.

Our world is not deterministic, so while the theoretical answer is a trivial yes, the actual answer is to reject the premises.

Can you please elaborate more? How do you know the world is not deterministic? What facts + what reasoning process led you to that conclusion? And why would that prevent the existence of deterministic reasoning processes? Are theorems in math non-deterministic? How do you reconcile your answer with math?

@user80226 Because it is quantum based, and those are inherently non-deterministic.

https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/m9ayzq/can_quantum_mechanics_be_deterministic/?rdt=57054

@user80226 The internet must be right, true ;-). And actually, the majority on that page seems to agree on "deterministic probability", which is not the same as "deterministic"! Thinking that we have reached the end of knowable things would be absurd, hence the possibility exists that we'll discover truly deterministic, hitherto hidden laws in the future.  But we have to base our arguments on something which is the current established science, and that is unequivocal: Nature as we know it is non-deterministic.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63811

@user80226 And to me that underlying fuzziness, even if unintuitive at first glance,  makes a lot of sense because a deterministic nature like Laplace envisioned would need infinite information (because all physical values like velocity and location and mass etc. would need to be infinitely precise) in a finite space (e.g, for every atom). That seems like an impossibility; the fuzziness permits the information held per spacetime volume to be finite, and that makes a lot of sense. The imprecise information then causes "imprecise" outcomes.

I don't want to drag this on too much but no true scotsman scientist would pretend to be able to predict events on the quantum level. "Deterministic probability" is the case for any coin toss (predictably 50%); but that's not deterministic. Some say "Undecided"; but that's rather "I am not convinced that the available evidence is all there is". All available evidence is that quantum events are probabilistic, i.e., contain a random element, i.e. are non-deterministic. Yes, as long as nothing "happens" the probability (!) wave function is deterministic....
